# No View Based Application Template XCode

Tags: xcode4, ios4

I've just installed the new iOS SDK and the View Based Application template has disappeared. Any ideas as to how to get it back?

Answer (score 12):

Now it's called "Single View Application". Take this template and it should work :-)

Comment: but  there is no class folder in that application?